# Combining several outputs into a table

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-4.0

Using Powershell I am trying to put the results of three commands into a table and output them to a file, then repeat the command forever. I can't figure out exactly how to format the table correctly.

This is my script

```
while (1){

    $ping = test-connection 8.8.8.8 -delay 1 -count 1
    $wifi = @{n='Status';e={get-netadapter -physical -name Wi-Fi | select Status}}
    $timestamp = @{n='TimeStamp';e={Get-Date}}

    $ping | format-table __SERVER, Address, ResponseTime, $timestamp, $wifi | out-file "C:\test-connection.txt" -append
    start-sleep -s 10
}
```

$ping gets the ping results of 8.8.8.8

$wifi gets the status of the wi-fi adapter

$timestamp gets the current time

The final output is meant to look something like this:

```
__SERVER  Address ResponseTime TimeStamp           Status      
--------  ------- ------------ ---------           ------      
Hostname  8.8.8.8           19 18/02/2019 10:19:23 Up
Hostname  8.8.8.8           19 18/02/2019 10:19:23 Up
Hostname  8.8.8.8           19 18/02/2019 10:19:23 Up
Hostname  8.8.8.8           19 18/02/2019 10:19:23 Up
...
```

However, with my current setup it does this:

```
__SERVER  Address ResponseTime TimeStamp           Status      
--------  ------- ------------ ---------           ------      
Hostname  8.8.8.8           20 18/02/2019 10:19:13 @{Status=Up}



__SERVER  Address ResponseTime TimeStamp           Status      
--------  ------- ------------ ---------           ------      
Hostname  8.8.8.8           19 18/02/2019 10:19:23 @{Status=Up}



__SERVER  Address ResponseTime TimeStamp           Status      
--------  ------- ------------ ---------           ------      
Hostname  8.8.8.8           20 18/02/2019 10:19:33 @{Status=Up}
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: in the while loop it is capturing the value one at a time. You need to capture the output as a whole out side the loop or you can create a psobject with arraylist and map the output respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to hide the table headers on subsequent writes, and also trim the output.

Try this:

```
while (1) {
    $ping = test-connection 8.8.8.8 -delay 1 -count 1
    $wifi = @{n='Status';e={get-netadapter -physical -name Wi-Fi | select -expand Status}}
    $timestamp = @{n='TimeStamp';e={Get-Date}}
    $path = "C:\test-connection.txt"
    $ping | ft __SERVER, Address, ResponseTime, $timestamp, $wifi -Hide:(Test-Path $path) | out-string | % {$_.trim()} | out-file $path -append
    start-sleep -s 10
}
```

Using `Format-Table` for file output is not a good idea though, it's meant for display in the console. Consider using CSV or a custom format.

Comment: Excellent that worked great thanks, i'll consider using a CSV if I come back to this in the future, but for now this works great.